# SELECT the newest record with a non null value in one column

Tags: mysql, null

I have table data which looks like this

```
id | keyword | count | date
1 | ipod | 200 | 2009-08-02
2 | ipod | 250 | 2009-09-01
3 | ipod | 150 | 2009-09-04
4 | ipod | NULL | 2009-09-07
```

Now what I am after is getting the count of the row which has the newest date but has a not null count. In which case row 3 with count 150.)

eg

```
SELECT `keyword`, `count` , max( `date` ) 
FROM `keywords` 
WHERE keyword = "ipod"
AND `count` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY keyword
```

This returned the right date but not the right count (returned 200). I also tried doing a left join on it's self.

```
SELECT `t1`.`keyword` , `t2`.`count` , max( `t1`.`id` )
FROM `keywords` `t1`
LEFT JOIN `keywords` `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
WHERE `t1`.`keyword` = 'ipod'
AND `t1`.`count` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `t1`.`keyword`
```

And this did get the max id but it didn't left-join onto that like I hoped and returned only 200.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `keyword`, `count` , `date`
FROM `keywords` 
WHERE keyword = "ipod"
AND `count` IS NOT NULL 
order by date desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: Argh, so simple... was just trying to get to fancy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm *sure* there's a better way, but in the mean time:

```
SELECT `count`
FROM `keywords` 
WHERE keyword = "ipod"
AND `count` IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Should fit your requirements. Note that LIMIT is not portable SQL, so it will only work for MySQL. The `ORDER BY` clause is necessary to force the database to sort by, well, date.

When I mentioned that there should be a better way, that's merely because of the way the `LIMIT` clause works, which is: The database has to fetch ALL rows that meet the query criteria, then simply truncates the result set to the desired amount specified by `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
SELECT `keyword`, `count`, `date` 
FROM `keywords` 
WHERE keyword = "ipod"
AND `count` IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 1
```