# SELECT all the latest non null records available based on date range in another table

Tags: mysql

Following on from this question [SELECT all the newest record distinct keyword with a non null value in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740280/select-all-the-newest-record-distinct-keyword-with-a-non-null-value-in-one-colum)

I now have a problem where I have this data

```
PRODUCT:
    id| product | amount| ownershipid
    1 | ipod    | 200   | 2
    2 | ipod    | 250   | 3
    3 | ipod    | 150   | 4
    4 | apple   | 100   | 1
    5 | apple   | 98    | 2
    6 | apple   | 500   | 3
    7 | itunes  | NULL  | 1
    8 | itunes  | 50    | 2
    9 | itunes  | NULL  | 3
   10 | itunes  | NULL  | 4

OWNERSHIP:
      ownershipid| start      | end
        1        | 2011-01-01 | 2011-12-31
        2        | 2012-01-01 | 2012-12-31
        3        | 2014-01-01 | 2014-12-31
        4        | 2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31
```

I need the most recent amount available for each product. I can not do an order by on ownershipId as the most recent data is from 2014. not from 2013. *OwnershipId is Autoincrement and we accept historic data.*

So, my result should return rows 2, 6 and 8.

Comment: Is "most recent" defined by `start` or `end`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming most recent is defined by `end`, you can do a somewhat convoluted join to get the result;

```
SELECT p.product, p.amount
FROM product p JOIN ownership o ON p.ownershipid = o.ownershipid
JOIN (
  SELECT p.product, MAX(o.end) end
  FROM product p JOIN ownership o ON p.ownershipid = o.ownershipid
  WHERE p.amount IS NOT NULL GROUP BY p.product) z 
ON p.product = z.product AND o.end = z.end;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b46a1/8).

The inner query gets the max date that has a non null amount per item.

The outer query gets the amount for that time/product.